# How do you call a JavaScript function that is in an embedded resource for an ASP.Net Custom control on the page that the control is hosted?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have an html editor custom control that I've been working on that has a basic undo/redo function that works well with all the functions that are part of the editor. The undo/redo function works off of 2 stacks (respectively named UndoStack and RedoStack), which when one of the other editor functions that modify the text property of the editor occur push on to the UndoStack.  For visualization, when Undo is clicked, pop is called and that value is stored to the redo stack.

However, the editor also interacts with some on-page AJAX functions that allow the user to insert already written text stored in our database.  What I want to accomplish here is to include the the JavaScript that is used to run the editor on the page and call the functions needed to push text on to the undo stack from the page.

As a side note, I used the solution provided by Rob2211 on [Embedded dll resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5633258/embedded-dll-resources) to get the script file on the page in question, but I would like to know how to call a function from it as it keeps saying that the function I want to call (pushUndoStack(), excuse the lack of creativity) is undefined.

Thanks

P.S. I generally code in C#, but some of the project is in VB.NET

Code Snippets: On Page

Register Page Directive

```
<%@ Register Assembly="WebControl.HtmlEditor" Namespace="WebControl.HtmlEditor"      TagPrefix="ec" %>
```

Code that grabs the HtmlEditor.js function

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= HtmlEditor.Resource.GetClientScript(Me.Page, "HtmlEditor.js")%>"></script>
```

Code Snippets: In C# file
The Resource Class

```
public class Resource
        {
            public static string GetClientScript(Page p, string file)
            {
                return p.ClientScript.GetWebResourceUrl(typeof(Resource), typeof(Resource).Namespace + ".Scripts." + file);
            }
        }
```

The assembly reference:

```
[assembly: WebResource("WebControl.HtmlEditor.Scripts.HtmlEditor.js", "text/javascript")]
```

The Prototype function: (Contains the following undo/redo functions)

```
WebControl.HtmlEditor.HtmlEditor.prototype =
{
.
.
.
}
```

From the Embedded JavaScript File: All undo/redo related functions.

```
getUndoStack: function () {
        return this.undoStack;
    },

    pushUndoStack: function (value) {
        this.undoStack.push(value);
    },

    popUndoStack: function () {
        return this.undoStack.pop();
    }, 

    getRedoStack: function () {
        return this.redoStack;
    },

    setRedoStack: function (value) {
        this.redoStack = value;
    },

    clearRedoStack: function () {
        var redoStack = this.getRedoStack();
        redoStack = new Array();
        this.setRedoStack(redoStack);
    },

    pushRedoStack: function (value) {
        this.redoStack.push(value)
    },

    popRedoStack: function () {
        return this.redoStack.pop();
    }
```

Comment: If it's on the page you should be able to call it normally. Have you peeked at the page source to verify it's rendered

Comment: @AndrewWalters - It is rendering as I would expect it to (with what appears to be an encoded URL, so I know it's there), however the JavaScript file is one large prototype function, and I'm not sure that makes a difference.  Is there a way to grab the a singular function out of the larger prototype function

Comment: What is the editor? Most of them support multiple editors in one page, and basically create instances for each one of them (with separate stacks). So you probably need to call pushUndoStack() to the editor object. Try to find the link of JS that creates the editor.

Comment: @TsanyoTsanev - The editor is .NET, I have its DLL registered on the page. The JavaScript that I want is the same that handles most of the editor functionality.  So is there I way I can reference the script methods used by the editor object on the ASPX page.

Comment: I'm not sure I entirely understand your setup, can you provide a code snippet of how you include and initialize the editor

Comment: @TsanyoTsanev - I'm not sure if that is all you were looking for in terms of some code snippets.

Comment: I'm not sure what this means: "grab singular function out of a larger prototype function". Could you post up a snippet of the javascript you're needing to call?

Comment: @AndrewWalters - I revisited the first sentence of your original post and looked in to what some jQuery solutions.  Using the $find('ControlID') method, I found that I was able to access the embedded JavaScript prototype function on the page the hosted the control and call the function that I needed.

Comment: @TsanyoTsanev - Thanks for the help your original post also led me to this jQuery solution for my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using jQuery.  Since the JavaScript function I needed was embedded in the HTML Editor custom control, the function that I needed was already available to the page, it just needed to a way to get to it. Using the $find('ControlID') method, I was able to search the DOM tree for the ID of 'Editor' and access everything that was included with the control, in this case, the function called pushUndoStack(). What lead me to this conclusion was a another part of this project that did the spell checking component of this project.

Thanks to @AndrewWalters and @TsanyoTsanev for the help.